# How to Change Global Variable in Android

Tags: java, android, maps

I want to make mapping a application , but I have a problem changing the global variable in my code. How do I change global latlng in global variable in `if else` in method bundle.. please give me solution..thank you..

```
public class Arahkan extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final int Direction = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int Exit = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    GoogleMap map;

    String tampil2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");

    public LatLng JAKARTA = new LatLng(-6.175467640504223,106.82718157768248); // HOW TO CHANGE THIS.. ??


    class Data {
        public Data(float lng, float lat, String title, String snippet, String icon) {
            super();
            this.lat = (float)lat;
            this.lng = (float)lng;
            this.title = title;
            this.snippet = snippet;
            this.icon = icon;
        }
        float lat;
        float lng;
        String title;
        String snippet;
        String icon;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.peta);
        if(tampil2.equalsIgnoreCase("coba")){

                //HERE... HOW TO CHANGE VALUE  FROM  VARIABEL LATLNG JAKARTA   ??

        }
        if(tampil2.equalsIgnoreCase("bisa")){

        }
```

Please Help me ...

Comment: so whats your problem ? are you getting error ?

Answer (score 0):

Latlng creates an immutable, the latitude & longitude member variables are "final", you cannot update it. [See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html)

For your scenario, I recommend Location class. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) is a good tutorial on using Location API